# Saving Image.fillAmount in variable/PlayerPrefs etc

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine

I have a progress bar like shown in the picture below, that adds a certain amount of `Image.fillAmount` after each level is completed. How can i save that fill amount, do i store it in another variable, using Player Prefs or what? To try to explain:

Level 1 is completed it adds one star

[image]

Level 2 is completed it adds one more star etc etc:

[image]

Here is part of my code in LevelControl that adds fillAmount:

```
private void LvlFinish()
    {
        loupe.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
        WinPanel.transform.SetAsLastSibling();
        WinPanel.SetActive(true);
        stars.fillAmount = 0.1f;
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Progress", amount);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Progress", 0));
}
```

I tried to save it using PlayerPrefs, but not working.

Left is LevelSelection panel, on right is panel when level completed.

[image]

Comment: A) how is `amount` related to `star.fillAmount` ? B) did you maybe mean `star.fillAmount += 0.1f;` ? Currently you are always setting it to exactly `0.1f` ...

Comment: A) I forgot to mention, it is a variable i tried to save fillAmount with.
B) i tried using also `star.fillAmount += 0.1f` but that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the current progress value and then add 0.1f (or whatever value you want) before you save it. Now you set the "fillAmount" to be 0.1f all the time.

```
   // Get the stored value. (I assume "amount" is a float variable)
   amount = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Progress", 0);
   // Add 10%
   amount += 0.1f;
   // Store the new value
   PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Progress", amount);
   PlayerPrefs.Save(); 
   // Update the stars image
   stars.fillAmount = amount
```

This will ensure that the progress is saved between sessions.

However, please note that PlayerPerfs is not a safe place to store progress data. It is very easy for the user to manually edit the values. If you store the data manually in Application.persistentDataPath you can make it harder for others to peek/change the values. It is actually not the location that makes it "safer", but now you have to serialize/deserialize it yourself and thus you can do it in binary or even add some simple encryption - well, binary is usually enough to keep most players away...

[Added] Here is a static class I use to serialize/deserialize objects to the persistent storage. There are of course hundreds of ways to do this, just google on it, but this works fine for me and is quite robust. It has no encryption but binary is usually good enough (see comment).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using UnityEngine;

/// <summary>
/// Tools to serialize and deserialize objects.
/// </summary>
public static class PersistenceTools
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Saves an object to the persistent storage.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the file.</param>
    /// <param name="data">The object to serialize.</param>
    public static void Save(string name, object data)
    {
        string filePathNameData = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, name) + ".dat";
        string filePathNameBakup = filePathNameData + "-bak";

        // Remove the old backup-file (if it exists) and rename the current (if it exists) to the backup name. 
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePathNameBakup))
            System.IO.File.Delete(filePathNameBakup);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePathNameData))
            System.IO.File.Move(filePathNameData, filePathNameBakup);

        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePathNameData, FileMode.Create))
        {
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(fileStream, data);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads an object from the persistent storage.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="L">The type of object we expect to deserialize.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the file to load (no path).</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static L Load<L>(string name)
    {
        string filePathNameData = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, name) + ".dat";
        string filePathNameBakup = filePathNameData + "-bak";

        try
        {
            return InternalLoad<L>(filePathNameData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex1)
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePathNameData))
                Debug.LogError("Could not read the file \"" + filePathNameData + "\". " + ex1.Message);
            try
            {
                return InternalLoad<L>(filePathNameBakup);
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePathNameBakup))
                    Debug.LogError("Could not read the file \"" + filePathNameBakup + "\". " + ex2.Message);
                return default(L);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Internal method to do the actual deserialization.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="L">The type of object we expect to deserialize.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="filePathName">The file with path to deserialize.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static L InternalLoad<L>(string filePathName)
    {
        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePathName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            return (L) binaryFormatter.Deserialize(fileStream);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes a file, including any backup version, from the persistent datastorage.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the file to delete (no path),</param>
    public static void Delete(string name)
    {
        string filePathNameData = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, name) + ".dat";
        string filePathNameBakup = filePathNameData + "-bak";

        // Remove the files. 
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePathNameBakup))
            System.IO.File.Delete(filePathNameBakup);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePathNameData))
            System.IO.File.Delete(filePathNameData);
    }
}
```

To be able to automatically serialize/deserialize an object it has to be declared as "[Serializable]". Here is a very simple example of a user slot to keep track of the user's name and current score.

```
[Serializable]
public class UserSlot
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

Here is an example:

```
// Create a slot and set some values.
UserSlot userSlot = new UserSlot() { UserName = "Andulf Games", Score = 13 };

...

// Save the slot (the filename will be "Slot1.dat").
PersistenceTools.Save("Slot1", userSlot);
```

To later load the information you simply call:

```
UserSlot userSlot = PersistenceTools.Load<UserSlot>("Slot1");
```

As you can see we will automatically rename the current file as .bak and generate a new .dat file each time we save. If we would crash while saving, or the data gets corrupted, we always have a backup file ready.

Comment: I will test this let you know if this works. And i know PlayerPrefs is not really safe, but this will not go public, for now, just some learning and testing. Yes, `amount` is a float variable, i forgot to mention that.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you so much. 

P.S. Where can i find good tutorials for simple encryption you mentioned above?

Comment: Just to be clear, whatever you do on a machine outside of your control, can't be fully secured. The user can always debug your code, freeze the memory, and so on. Real encryption must be done externally where the user can't interfere - but I am quite sure you don't need that level of security. I will include the code I usually use.

Comment: Yes, i don't need that level of security right now, but it will come in handy in the future. Thank you, have a good day.